# How to find the target-os value from a Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-build

In a `Dockerfile`, I want to find the target OS that the docker image being built for. In the [documents](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-platform/) it states that build args are available in the `Dockerfile` automatically.

I added the following in the `Dockerfile`.

```
FROM --platform=$BUILDPLATFORM golang:alpine AS build
# ...
FROM image-${TARGETOS}
```

When building the image on a windows platform, I get the following error

> failed to parse platform : "" is an invalid component of "": platform specifier component must match "^[A-Za-z0-9_-]+$": invalid argument

How can I get the target OS value on Linux and Windows?

Here is the command I use to build the image

```
docker build -f Dockerfile --platform=windows/amd64 -t project:latest .
```

Or,

```
docker build -f Dockerfile --platform=linux/amd64 -t project:latest .
```

Answer (score 0):

In Docker, the `--platform` flag is used to specify the target platform for the build, like `linux/amd64`, `linux/arm64`, `windows/amd64`, etc.

You can pass the target OS as an environment variable from outside the Docker build process, for example, using a build argument.

In your Dockerfile, you might use `ARG` to define a build-time variable:

```
ARG TARGETOS
FROM --platform=${TARGETOS} golang:alpine AS build
# ...
FROM image-${TARGETOS}
```

Then, when building the image, you specify the `TARGETOS`:

```
docker build --build-arg TARGETOS=linux/amd64 -t your-image-name .
```

Comment: This does not fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to read Tonis' blogpost re: multi-platform builds w/Docker and Dockerfile.  [*Faster Multi-Platform Builds*](https://www.docker.com/blog/faster-multi-platform-builds-dockerfile-cross-compilation-guide/) which demonstrates how Docker automatically creates global-scoped platform variables (e.g., **TARGETARCH**, **TARGETOS**) when `--platform=<your-platform-here>`; argument is supplied to 'buildx'.

Based on the automatic creation of those variables, it is relatively straight-forward to map them into a build platform toolchain specification.  Example: Kitware CMake - you can set **CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR** to value of **TARGETARCH**.  Docker should automagically provide the 'correct' set of platform variables when the build/buildx is invoked with more than 1 valid target platform (for instance: `build buildx ... --platform=linux/amd64,linux/arm64`).